# How to unmerge a family tree in Family Tree Builder 8.0?

Tags: gedcom, family-tree-builder

I have two merged family trees and I would like to know if there is a way to break them back into two separate family trees?

I downloaded the My Heritage [Family Tree Builder 8.0](https://www.myheritage.com/family-tree-builder). I got the GEDCOM file from my cousin which I uploaded into the program. When I seen that both our family trees were in the one GEDCOM file, I was a bit disappointed and that is why I am asking the question.

Comment: Hi, Dean, welcome! If you downloaded MyHeritage's free program, that is Family Tree *Builder* (not Maker). I have edited your question to reflect that.

Comment: I'm a total novice to genealogy. I'm wondering where to begin with researching my family history. Is Family Tree Maker worth trying? I have just discovered about [family tree builders](http://www.beautifullife.info/web-design/best-family-tree-builders). I have read that Myheritage allows photographs to be incorporated and has worldwide genealogy community, helping its users link to relatives overseas.

Comment: I've converted this non-answer by @RomaxShpek to a comment temporarily because it isn't an answer to the question.  But both of you have confused Family Tree Maker, the program that integrates with Ancestry, with Family Tree Builder, the program that integrates with MyHeritage.  Please make use of the material in the [help] to learn more about how the site works, and when writing questions, please take more care to ask a question that asks about the correct program.

Answer (score 3):

The MyHeritage site has an [FAQ entry](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/tour) for this. It walks you though the progress with pictures and everything.

Summary: You goto to `File` -> `Export GEDCOM`, fill in the dialog until you get to the "Pick content" section. There you can pick the option `Include only selected people`. Choose the person you want the tree to start with and click `Edit` to select Descendents, Spouses and Ancestors, so that you get the complete tree. Then save the file.

You can now open the exported file again with Family Tree Builder or upload it into MyHeritage or any other program/website that supports the GEDCOM format.